# Simple javascript and image for help text on webpage

Tags: javascript

I really want to put a little question mark image next to some of the input fields on my for so the user can click and get a little box to come up and provide some help text.  A tooltip might work for this too.  Here is what I would like:

1. Script for having a little text area pop up when user clicks on an image (not a new window, just an area for text and links that goes away when the users clicks elsewhere)
2. A nice little square image of a question mark.

Thanks!

Comment: Do we have a standard "please do my job for me" tag? Alternatively, can we implement a charging model for it?

Comment: @Rob: There is the 'plzsendtehcodez' tag, which may be what you're after.

Comment: Sorry guys.  It seemed valid to me because I really don't know how to do this, and I need help on how to make this little box come up.  I guess I should phrase differently so as to not piss off already angry programmers.  If I had said, "how do I do this?" wouldn't you be a lot less mad?  Chill out.

Comment: I agree that this may not be the greatest question, but it doesn't have anything in it that would really warrant the down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done purely in CSS if you don't mind it appearing on hover instead of on click. Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
      a.helpAnchor {
        position:relative;
        text-decoration:none;
      }
      a.helpAnchor .helpIcon {
        position:absolute;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:24px;
        font-weight:bold;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        color:#ff0;
        background-color:#88f;
      }
      a.helpAnchor .helpText { 
        display:none; 
      }
      a.helpAnchor:hover .helpText {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        width:150px;
        top:10px;
        left:20px;
        background-color:#eff;
        color:black;
        border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="helpAnchor">
      <div class="helpIcon">?</div>
      <div class="helpText">
        <h1>Help Text</h1>
        <p>This text is very helpful!</p>
        <p>And so is this!</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

It would look better - and simplify the CSS - if the question mark icon was an image.
The CSS for the help text also needs adjusting for taste.

Answer (score 2):

I use [BeautyTips](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bt), a jQuery plugin for displaying info tooltips/ballons, check the [demos](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html).

[image]
<sub>(source: [lullabot.com](https://www.lullabot.com/files/u2/diwd-schedule-2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thanks CMS - I browsed this randomly and think beauty tips look fantastic.  Something much more basic than this was on my todo list for my current site - I've no need to bother now!